# Extract main titles from pdf using java

Tags: java, pdf, extract

I am looking for a library or tool to extract main titles from a pdf document(title, abstract, conclusion)
using java I search a lot but I didn't find what I want exactly any recommendations?
Thank you

Comment: More information would be helpful. Are you looking for a standalone tool? If not, what have you tried so far? Do you have any code whatsoever? Either case, [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) could be what you are looking for, as it has a few command-line utilities.

Answer (score 1):

Try **Apache Tika**, is basically a toolkit that extracts data from documents, including PDFs.

More Info: [What is the easiest way to extract data from a PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831765/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-extract-data-from-a-pdf)